# Multiline Tabs in an FMX TTabControl

Tags: delphi, tabcontrol, firemonkey

There is a well known property `Multiline` in VCL TTabConrol that allows the tabs to be placed in multiple rows like this.

[image]

But there is no such property in FMX library. Is multiline presentation of tabs possible in FMX applications?

Comment: Well, VCL has been around since 1995 and is based on standard Windows controls, so there was a whole lot of room for such features. FMX on the other hand was released in 2011 and is based on common similarities between all platforms (Windows, OS-X, iOS, and Android). So as you can imagine, Firemonkey is still quite far from all the bells and whistles that VCL has.

Comment: The way this is implemented in the Win32 control (i.e. as used by VCL controls) is probably the single most confusing UI design I've encountered. Don't present multiline tabs to your users unless you want to drive them away.

Comment: Indeed, adding to my comment and David's, having multi-line tabs died off way back in Windows XP. Only apps I see like this are ones that were designed back in those days. In fact, I prefer having left/right navigation arrows (or handling mouse wheel scroll events) to move left/right to see more tabs.

Comment: Thank you, David Heffernan and @Jerry-Dodge. Will it be correct to conclude in the following way? It can be done but is not naturally  supported by FMX and is not worth being coded.

Comment: @asd-tm That would be my conclusion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not possible, at least not out of the box. If you want to add support, take a closer look at `TTabControl.RealignTabs;`.

Comment: Thank you, Sebastian. I shall consider your idea.

Answer (score 0):

not perfect but work

```
unit BFSTabControl;

interface

uses
  System.Classes, System.Types, System.Math, System.Rtti, System.SysUtils
  , FMX.TabControl, FMX.Controls;

type
  TBFSTabControl = class(TTabControl)
  private
    rttc,rtti: TRttiType;
    rtFRealigningTabs,rtFContent,rtFBackground,rtFNoItemsContent,rtFClientRect,rtFTabContentSize,rtFTabBarRect,rtFLeftOffset,rtFRightOffset: TRttiField;
    FMultiLineTabs: Boolean;
    procedure SetMultiLineTabs(const Value: Boolean);

  protected
    procedure RealignTabs; override;
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;

    property MultiLineTabs: Boolean read FMultiLineTabs write SetMultiLineTabs;
  end;

implementation

constructor TBFSTabControl.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  rttc := TRTTIContext.Create.GetType(TTabControl);
  rtFRealigningTabs := rttc.GetField('FRealigningTabs');
  rtFContent := rttc.GetField('FContent');
  rtFBackground := rttc.GetField('FBackground');
  rtFNoItemsContent := rttc.GetField('FNoItemsContent');
  rtFClientRect := rttc.GetField('FClientRect');
  rtFTabContentSize := rttc.GetField('FTabContentSize');
  rtFTabBarRect := rttc.GetField('FTabBarRect');

  rtti := TRTTIContext.Create.GetType(TTabItem);
  rtFLeftOffset := rtti.GetField('FLeftOffset');
  rtFRightOffset := rtti.GetField('FRightOffset');

  FMultiLineTabs := True;

  inherited;
end;

type
  TFakeTabItem = class(TTabItem);
  TOpenControl = class(TControl);

function GetIdxBeg(ARow: Integer; CountInRow: array of Integer): Integer;
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  Result := 0;
  if ARow > 0 then
    for I := 0 to ARow-1 do
      Result := Result +CountInRow[I];
end;

function CalcRowWidth(ARow: Integer; ItemsWidth: array of Single; CountInRow: array of Integer): Single;
var
  I, IdxBeg: Integer;
begin
  IdxBeg := GetIdxBeg(ARow,CountInRow);
  Result := 0;
  for I := IdxBeg to IdxBeg +CountInRow[ARow] - 1 do
    Result := Result +ItemsWidth[I];
end;

procedure TBFSTabControl.RealignTabs;
const
  MinHeight = 5;
var
  I, J, CountVisibleItems, RowCount, BegRowIdx, RowIdx, ActiveRow, Surplus: Integer;
  CurX, CurY, LLeftOffset, LRightOffset, RowWidth, TotalWidth, TotalHeight, MaxHeight, CurRowWidth, ItemWidth, ExtraWidth, ExtraWidthRow: Single;
  ItemRect: TRectF;
  LItem: TFakeTabItem;
  ItemsRowIdx, CountInRow: array of Integer;
  ItemsWidth: array of Single;
  VisibleLItems: array of TFakeTabItem;

  FClientRect: TRectF;
  FContent: TContent;
  FBackground: TControl;
  FTabContentSize: TSizeF;
  FTabBarRect: TRectF;
begin
  if (not FMultiLineTabs) or (FMultiLineTabs and (EffectiveTabPosition in [TTabPosition.None, TTabPosition.Dots])) then begin
    inherited;
    Exit;
  end;

  if rtFRealigningTabs.GetValue(Self).AsBoolean then
    Exit;

  FContent := rtFContent.GetValue(Self).AsObject as TContent;
  if ([csLoading, csDestroying] * ComponentState = []) then begin
    rtFRealigningTabs.SetValue(Self,True);
    try
      // Initialization
      FClientRect := LocalRect;
      FBackground := TControl(rtFBackground.GetValue(Self).AsObject);
      if FBackground <> nil then
        FClientRect := FBackground.Padding.PaddingRect(FClientRect);
      if ResourceControl <> nil then
        FClientRect := ResourceControl.Margins.PaddingRect(FClientRect);
      rtFClientRect.SetValue(Self,TValue.From<TRectF>(FClientRect));

      // Get only visible items
      CountVisibleItems := 0;
      SetLength(VisibleLItems,TabCount);
      for I := 0 to TabCount - 1 do begin
        LItem := TFakeTabItem(Tabs[I]);
        LItem.FDesignSelectionMarks := True;
        if LItem.Visible then begin
          VisibleLItems[CountVisibleItems] := LItem;
          Inc(CountVisibleItems);
        end;
      end;

      // Calc minimum row count, total width and max height
      TotalWidth := 0;
      RowCount := 0;
      CurRowWidth := 0;
      MaxHeight := MinHeight;
      SetLength(ItemsWidth,CountVisibleItems);
      for I := 0 to CountVisibleItems - 1 do begin
        LItem := VisibleLItems[I];
        MaxHeight := Max(MaxHeight, Trunc(LItem.Info.Size.cy + LItem.Margins.Top + LItem.Margins.Bottom));
        ItemWidth := LItem.Info.Size.cx + LItem.Margins.Left + LItem.Margins.Right;
        ItemsWidth[I] := ItemWidth;
        if ItemWidth > FClientRect.Width then begin
          if CurRowWidth <> 0 then
            Inc(RowCount);
          CurRowWidth := 0;
          Inc(RowCount);
        end else if (CurRowWidth +ItemWidth) > FClientRect.Width then begin
          CurRowWidth := ItemWidth;
          Inc(RowCount);
        end else
          CurRowWidth := CurRowWidth +ItemWidth;

        if (I = CountVisibleItems - 1) and (ItemWidth <= FClientRect.Width) then
          Inc(RowCount);

        TotalWidth := TotalWidth +ItemWidth;
      end;

      // Сhecking that it is not necessary to line-align
      if (TotalWidth+1) < FClientRect.Width then begin
        rtFRealigningTabs.SetValue(Self,False);
        inherited;
        Exit;
      end else
        TControl(rtFNoItemsContent.GetValue(Self).AsObject).Visible := False;

      // Calc of extra additive for full filling
      ExtraWidth := Trunc((RowCount*FClientRect.Width -TotalWidth)/CountVisibleItems);
      if ExtraWidth < 0 then
        ExtraWidth := 0;

      // Filling from left to right line by line getting row index for each item
      RowIdx := 0;
      CurRowWidth := 0;
      SetLength(ItemsRowIdx,CountVisibleItems);
      for I := 0 to CountVisibleItems - 1 do begin
        ItemsRowIdx[I] := RowIdx;
        ItemWidth := ItemsWidth[I] +ExtraWidth;
        if (CurRowWidth = 0) and (ItemWidth > FClientRect.Width) and (RowIdx < (RowCount-1)) then begin
          CurRowWidth := 0;
          Inc(RowIdx);
        end else if ((CurRowWidth +ItemWidth) > FClientRect.Width) and (RowIdx < (RowCount-1)) then begin
          CurRowWidth := ItemWidth;
          Inc(RowIdx);
          ItemsRowIdx[I] := RowIdx;
        end else
          CurRowWidth := CurRowWidth +ItemWidth;
      end;

      // Calc count items in row
      SetLength(CountInRow,RowCount);
      for I := 0 to RowCount - 1 do
        CountInRow[I] := 0;
      for I := 0 to CountVisibleItems - 1 do
        CountInRow[ItemsRowIdx[I]] := CountInRow[ItemsRowIdx[I]] +1;

      // Checking sum of items width in row and resort them
      for I := RowCount-1 downto 1 do begin
        if CountInRow[I] = 1 then
          Continue;
        while True do begin
          if CalcRowWidth(I,ItemsWidth,CountInRow) <= FClientRect.Width then
            Break;
          BegRowIdx := GetIdxBeg(I,CountInRow);
          ItemsRowIdx[BegRowIdx] := ItemsRowIdx[BegRowIdx] -1;
          CountInRow[I-1] := CountInRow[I-1] +1;
          CountInRow[I] := CountInRow[I] -1;
          if CountInRow[I] = 1 then
            Break;
        end;
        if CalcRowWidth(I-1,ItemsWidth,CountInRow) <= FClientRect.Width then
          Break;
      end;

      // Get row with active tab
      ActiveRow := -1;
      for I := 0 to CountVisibleItems - 1 do
        if VisibleLItems[I] = ActiveTab then begin
          ActiveRow := ItemsRowIdx[I];
          Break;
        end;

      // Initialization of bounds
      FTabContentSize := TSizeF.Create(FClientRect.Width, MaxHeight*RowCount);
      rtFTabContentSize.SetValue(Self,TValue.From<TSizeF>(FTabContentSize));
      FTabBarRect := TRectF.Create(TPointF.Zero, FClientRect.Width, MaxHeight*RowCount);
      case EffectiveTabPosition of
        TTabPosition.Top:
          FTabBarRect.Offset(FClientRect.TopLeft);
        TTabPosition.Bottom:
          FTabBarRect.Offset(FClientRect.Left, FClientRect.Bottom - FTabBarRect.Height);
      end;
      rtFTabBarRect.SetValue(Self,TValue.From<TRectF>(FTabBarRect));
      FContent.BoundsRect := TabBarRect;

      // Update tab positions
      TotalHeight := 0;
      if EffectiveTabPosition = TTabPosition.Bottom then
        TotalHeight := MaxHeight;
      BegRowIdx := 0;
      for I := 0 to RowCount - 1 do begin
        if I > 0 then BegRowIdx := BegRowIdx +CountInRow[I-1];
        RowWidth := 0;
        for J := BegRowIdx to BegRowIdx+CountInRow[I] -1 do
          RowWidth := RowWidth +ItemsWidth[J];
        LLeftOffset := rtFLeftOffset.GetValue(VisibleLItems[BegRowIdx]).AsType<Single>;
        LRightOffset := rtFLeftOffset.GetValue(VisibleLItems[BegRowIdx+CountInRow[I] -1]).AsType<Single>;
        ExtraWidthRow := Trunc((FClientRect.Width +LLeftOffset +LRightOffset -RowWidth)/CountInRow[I]);
        Surplus := Trunc(Max(FClientRect.Width +LLeftOffset +LRightOffset -RowWidth -ExtraWidthRow*CountInRow[I], 0));
        CurX := TabContentPosition - LLeftOffset;
        if I = ActiveRow then begin
          if EffectiveTabPosition = TTabPosition.Bottom then
            CurY := 0
          else
            CurY := (RowCount - 1)*MaxHeight
        end else
          CurY := TotalHeight;
        for J := BegRowIdx to BegRowIdx+CountInRow[I] -1 do begin
          LItem := VisibleLItems[J];
          ItemRect := TRectF.Create(TPointF.Create(CurX, CurY), LItem.Info.Size.cx +ExtraWidthRow, MaxHeight);
          ItemRect := LItem.Margins.PaddingRect(ItemRect);
          if J = BegRowIdx+CountInRow[I] -1 then
            ItemRect.Width := ItemRect.Width + Surplus;
          LItem.BoundsRect := ItemRect;
          CurX := CurX + ItemRect.Width + LItem.Margins.Left + LItem.Margins.Right;
        end;

        if I <> ActiveRow then
          TotalHeight := TotalHeight+MaxHeight;
      end;

      if not FDisableAlign then
        Realign;
    finally
      rtFRealigningTabs.SetValue(Self,False);
    end;
  end else
    FContent.Height := 0;
end;

procedure TBFSTabControl.SetMultiLineTabs(const Value: Boolean);
begin
  FMultiLineTabs := Value;
  Realign;
end;

end.
```

[image]